# Read a docx file in C# using OpenXml

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

I am new to C# and OpenXml. I need help with reading a .docx file and storing each paragraph in the Array. 
I am Using OpenXml to read a word(.docx) file. I was able to read the file and print it. But the problem is I was only able to print the concatenated paragraph. I couldn't find a way to store each paragraph as array of Strings(Like in Python using docx library you automatically store paragraph as a list of string, I was looking something similar to that).

```
using System;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenWordprocessingDocumentReadonly(@"E:\WordDocTest\Test.docx");
        }
        public static void OpenWordprocessingDocumentReadonly(string filepath)
        {
            // Open a WordprocessingDocument based on a filepath.
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, false))
            {
                // Assign a reference to the existing document body.  
                Body body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                Console.WriteLine(body.InnerText);
                wordDocument.Close();
             }
        }
     }
}
```

Test.docx Looks Like this

## 1. Test

This is Test 1. 
Test1 part a.

## 2. noTest

This is Test2.

The Output that I got was : TestThis is Test 1.Test1 part a.noTestThis is Test 2.
What I want to learn is about the way to store each paragraph or line in an Array of String and be able to iterate through that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nirakar Nepal You could try loop through the paras list and extract the next sibling, e.g. 'foreach (var para in paras) { richTextBox1.Text += para.NextSibling().InnerText + "\n"; } ' This of course assumes you are printing the output to a richtextbox. This will show whatever happens to be after the headingYou can avoid using arrays and instead unleash the wonderful power of Openxml combined with Linq and Lists. If you want to work with paragraphs you could create a list lik this:

```
var paras = body.OfType<Paragraph>();
```

You can then expand on this to return specific elements using Where, for example:

```
var paras = body.OfType<Paragraph>()
.Where(p => p.ParagraphProperties != null &&                   
p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId != null &&     
p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId.Val.Value.Contains("Heading1")).ToList();
```

To return the paragraph which follows the heading you could try loop through the paras list and extract the next sibling, e.g.

```
foreach (var para in paras) { 
richTextBox1.Text += para.NextSibling().InnerText + "\n"; 
}
```

This of course assumes you are printing the output to a richtextbox. This will show whatever happens to be after the heading. Again your code code could include .where to filter the results

Comment: I am new to this,
I couldn't understand what Dim is (Is it a var).
I was thinking if you could explain little bit more on how to create a list and using Where in C#. Thank you.

Comment: `Dim` is VB, the C# equivalent is `var`. Not sure why answer uses VB.

Comment: Apologies I was coding in VB ll day today so yes I should have used C# and yes in that case use var. So just to clarify I have edited my original answer

Comment: Thank you @JohnDaPleaserofWimmin, 
The code you mentioned stores only Heading1 to the List(As a result I was able to access Test noTest). But I was looking to access the paragraph inside the heading1 if not store every paragraph to the List. Do you think you can help me with that.

Comment: @Nirakar Nepal You could try loop through the paras list and extract the next sibling. This will show whatever happens to be after the heading. I've updated my answer to illustrate this.